# strange situation with printf

Tags: c++, embedded

I write this easy program, with st nucleo and Shiled GSM (SIM900). I want save the answer in a string variable.
I save the data in variable.  All work well but when I use the printf command,
I have this error:

> > ```
> > cannot pass object of non-pod type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char>') through variadic method; call will abort at runtime (Wnon-pod-varargs)
> > ```

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <string>
Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX); // PC comunication
Serial SIM900(PA_9, PA_10);    // serial comunication
 DigitalOut myled(LED1);
 DigitalOut sim_power(D9);  //power gsm900
string result;
char x;
int i;
void callback_rx() {
while (SIM900.readable()) {
 x = SIM900.getc();
 result += x;
 pc.putc(x);  }
 pc.printf("%s",result);  //her i have error
 }
 void controlAT(){ 
 result = "";
 SIM900.printf("AT\r");
 wait_ms(1000);  }

 int main()
 {

power();
 pc.printf("\r\n GSM 900 TEST\n"); 
 SIM900.attach(&callback_rx);  //call interrupt
 SIM900.baud(9600);
while(1) {
controlAT();
wait_ms(300);
}
}
```

I don't know where is the problem; can you help me?

Comment: need to call `.c_str()` on the string `pc.printf("%s",result.c_str()); `

Comment: This is not C but C++, so use the appropriate IO features that C++ provides.

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler...

Comment: As the warning says, it's invalid to pass a non-POD, "plain old data",  type in  a variable argument list (where the `...` is in a function prototype). Basically only built-in types or plain C-style structures can be passed in a vararg list.

Comment: Voting to reopen: this problem is not a simple typographic error.  The problem is that certain C++ types cannot be passed in a variable argument list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 pc.printf("%s", result.c_str());
```

`s` conversion specification requires a C string argument (i.e., a null terminated array of  `char`).

Comment: In addition to this specific case, it's a general rule that non-POD types cannot be passed in a vararg list.

Answer (score 1):

While using %s specificator you must use C style string in printf. If you use printf you must convert it to C style string by using c_str(). Following solution will work in your case

```
 1. pc.printf("%s", result.c_str());
```

Comment: `printf` is a function on `pc`, it might not call `cout`

Comment: `Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX);`

Comment: Now, I understand. Editing the post now :)